# "which python" keeps showing python2 path after changing the alias of "python" to python3

Tags: python, bash

I'm a Mac user. When I typed `python` in the terminal, it launched python2 located at `/usr/bin/python` But I wish to use python3. So I added `alias python='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7'` and
`alias python2='/usr/bin/python'` in the `~/.bash_profile`

Then when I typed `python` again, it launched python3 as my wish, and I can still use python2 when typing `python2` in the terminal. However, if I type `which python`, the terminal still showed me `/usr/bin/python` (the old python2 path) plus there's no output if I type `which python2`.

I am not familiar with bash. I am not sure if this has anything to do with environment variables. I tried to search. But still couldn't solve this inconsistency. Can anyone please let me know how I can obtain the correct python3 path when typing `which python`? Thanks!

Comment: Use `type python`, not `which python`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which` shows you executables in your `PATH`, but no aliases. Use the Bash built-in `type` instead, which shows you aliases as well; use `type -a` to see all locations containing the executable.

See also [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/118235) on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am still curious about how I can make `which python` to detect the actual python3 executable? Could you please talk more about it?

Comment: Add it to your PATH. By default which shows you the first match so if you add your python3 location to it make sure to prepend it.

Comment: @JeffXi Even if you use `which -a` to print all (and not just the first) matching executables, you won't see aliases.